# Oracle PL/SQL Bubble-Sorting - ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at line 12

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is the code:

```
declare  
  p_arr dbms_sql.Number_Table;  
  i pls_integer;  
  procedure do_sort(p_arr in out dbms_sql.Number_Table, p_asc in boolean default null, p_nulls_last in boolean default null) is  
  x pls_integer; 
  p_temp number; 
  begin    
  for i in 1..p_arr.COUNT-1  
    loop  
      for x in 2..p_arr.COUNT  
      loop  
        if p_arr(x) < p_arr(x-1)  
        then  
          p_temp := p_arr(x-1);  
          p_arr(x-1) := p_arr(x);  
          p_arr(x) := p_temp;  
        end if; 
      end loop; 
    end loop; 
    return;  
  end;  
begin  
  p_arr(-1) := 0;  
  p_arr(0) := -2;  
  p_arr(1) := 10.1;  
  p_arr(2) := null;   
  p_arr(3) := 10.1;  
  p_arr(4) := -1;  
  do_sort(p_arr);  
  i := p_arr.first;  
  while i is not null loop  
    dbms_output.put_line('arr('||i||') = '||nvl(to_char(p_arr(i)), 'null')||';');  
    i := p_arr.next(i);  
  end loop;  
end;
```

It gives me an error on line 12 - "No data found".
Respectively, the procedure "do_sort" on line 29 also fails.

Seems like the problem with nested loop, which I can't figure out for now.
When there is only "first-level" loop with some code in it, such as assigning new values to collection - it performs well.

Sorting block outside of procedure body also works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for x in 2..p_arr.COUNT loop if p_arr(x) < p_arr(x-1)` ... you have 6 items in the array, but p_arr(4) is the last item. No wonder this fails, since p_arr(5) and p_arr(6) don't exist...

Comment: Why did you decide to populate your table with indexes starting at -1, out of interest? I could see you might pick zero based on other languages' behaviour; but why -1?

Comment: It is specified in task I was given. I also tried methods FIRST, LAST, PRIOR, NEXT on p_arr, but I couldn't implement the sorting with them.

Comment: Case is closed thanks to Alex Poole.

Comment: Is it better to leave the original code as a reference or edit it?

Comment: @Alexound - no, don't change the code in the question now, that would invalidate the answer and not help anyone else with a similar problem later. [See the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for what do to when a question is answered. [And this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You're filling your number table with specific indexes:

```
  p_arr(-1) := 0;  
  p_arr(0) := -2;  
  p_arr(1) := 10.1;  
  p_arr(2) := null;   
  p_arr(3) := 10.1;  
  p_arr(4) := -1;
```

But when you loop you are using index values from 1 to the count of elements, which is 6. There is no element with index 5 or 6, and when you try to refer to `p_arr(5)` there is no such element - hence the error. And you miss out those with indexes -1 and 0.

It works if you re-index your initial values:

```
  p_arr(1) := 0;  
  p_arr(2) := -2;  
  p_arr(3) := 10.1;  
  p_arr(4) := null;   
  p_arr(5) := 10.1;  
  p_arr(6) := -1;
```

which then gets output:

```
arr(1) = -2;
arr(2) = 0;
arr(3) = 10.1;
arr(4) = null;
arr(5) = -1;
arr(6) = 10.1;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Notice what happens with your null value though... you cannot compare null with anything else, so `p_arr(x) < p_arr(x-1)` is undefined (but not true) when the null element is evaluated on both sides of that comparison. So, it doesn't move. You would need to decide where you want nulls to end up to determine how to modify the code to achieve that.

If you have a specific reason for starting your indexing at -1 instead of 1, you *could* still do that, and change the references inside your loop to be `p_arr(x+2)` etc., but it would be more confusing and error-prone. Or you coudl change your loop ranges to handle that instead:

```
  for i in -1..p_arr.COUNT - 1 -- 2 less than previously, on each end of range
    loop  
      for x in 0..p_arr.COUNT - 2 -- 2 less than previously, on each end of range
      loop
```

... which gets the same result, using your original table population starting from index -1. [Oracle Live SQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/el8xzp3r52yf1ycrvu6eflwvu).

The indexes used inside the loops have to align with the indexes you use to populate the table, however you do it.

Comment: I've tried to change index values, and null value, temporarily, still same error. I'm running this code in Oralce Live SQL. Also tried this in PLSQL Developer - same error.

Comment: @Alexound - I added a way to adjust the loop indexes, including a link to a Live SQL demo. The nulls aren't breaking it, they just aren't moving.

Comment: Alex, thank you very much for your help. Looks like I've missed "-2" on the second-loop. Now it's working.

Comment: concerning the null values, you could wrap both sides of the comparison with the nvl() function to replace null values with the respective minimum or maximum value. you just need to decide on which end you want the null values.

Comment: Yeah, I'd explicitly check for null values instead, but you have to decide what to do with them before you decide how.